# How do I update an Object Map inside a Firebase Object?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Newbie here!

So I am using Firebase. I basically have this condensed structure. I got to this structure by trying to follow what I have read (No arrays, etc).

I have an User Object which needs to contain a list of stuff. So I have ended up with this kind of thing in the database.

```
{
   name: "clark"
   friends: {
       billyTheKid: true,
       butcherOfBakersfield: true
   }
}
```

When I add a friend, I am doing this (again forgive the poor names)

```
this.$firebaseUserObserver.update({
  friends: {
    [friendID]: true
  }
});
```

When I do this, and I return to my example, then `BillyTheKid` is deleted and replaced by `ButcherOfBakersfield`.

I feel like I am getting `set` behavior despite using `update` so I must be handling the structure incorrectly.

Would anyone be able to offer me guidance?

Comment: What happens if you go down one level before doing .update?
Ex. $firebaseUserObserver.object("friends").update({ [friendId]: true}) ?
Im not really familiar with the angularfire2 syntax, but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a lead Arneson! I appreciate it.  It seems `object` or `child` didn't exist on that observable.  Which is a [FirebaseObjectObservable](https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_object_observable_.firebaseobjectobservable.html).  However, there is a `$ref` property which does lead to `child` so I think I can work with this.

Comment: Great, hope it'll work out.

Comment: @arneson I managed to get this working almost exactly like you said! If you want to alter that suggestion to `$firebaseUserObserver.$ref.child("friends").update({ [friendId]: true})` then I will happily accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Added it as an answer instead. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you go down one level before doing *.update*? Ex.

```
$firebaseUserObserver.$ref.child("friends").update({ [friendId]: true})
```

I think the update statement basically replaces each child of the node, instead of replacing the entire node which is what .set does. Basically it does a set on each child. Because of this it only works one level down in the structure.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `update()` on a ref, iterates over the properties of the object you pass in and then calls `set()` for each of those. So you're indeed replacing the `friends` with each call.

The proper solution is to call `update()` on the right level in the tree:

```
this.$firebaseUserObserver.child('friends').update({
    [friendID]: true
});
```

But in this case that is not even needed, you can set call `set()` for the specific friend:

```
this.$firebaseUserObserver.child('friends').child(friendId).set(true);
```